# multiple tabs and php uploader

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I made admin in page in order to let the user add main data of page, name, second name, address, image 1(php uploader with thumbs) , image 2(php uploader with thumbs),gallery uploader (php and jquery)

then I faced an issue with multiple tabs and I solved it. in main data

The problem is in the 3 uploaders

Because I used to upload images with its thumbnails with different size, so I have to make it with sessions in order to know where to upload and which is the size

The problem is in multiple tabs issue the sessions are overwritten

**So how I can make alias or sessions to be specific in each window but with same name?** Is it possible?

> **N.B: I mean multiple tabs in browser with same sessions name**

Comment: i presume you are talking about target="", when openening a new window or tab give it the proper name.

Comment: If relevant, post some code parts

Comment: i mean multiple tabs in browser with same sessions name

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean tabs like as in jQuery UI tabs or some other UI library?

If so, because all the data in the tabs are in reality on one page, in one form, if you have more than one image to upload (say one on each tab), you will need to make sure that the data in the form for each of the multiple images is in an array - one element for each image.

You will then need to loop through the array to get the info for the multiple images when you submit the form.

Comment: i mean multiple tabs in browser with same sessions name